# VBA Vlookup with copy/paste and date/time stamp

Tags: vba, vlookup

first post here and relative newbie to everything VBA!

Ideally, what I am looking for is a macro that will take a value entered into a cell, VLOOKUP against an array on another sheet and paste the value in the next blank cell in that row, with a date/time stamp in the next blank adjacent cell. I'd like to be able to keep the original data so that if the macro runs again it doesn't overwrite any previously pasted data.

For example, the data to copy/paste will be entered into cell D2 on sheet 2, the value to lookup is in B2 on sheet 2. The array to look against is Sheet 6 Column A with columns B and C for the pasted value and date/time stamp respectively.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Ant.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please use recording macro and edit the code as per your requirement.

Comment: if any issue post it to this thread.

Comment: Typically here you'd post the code you already tried, along with a description of what error(s) you're seeing, or how the code doesn't quite do what you expect. If you don't know *any* VBA then there are a ton of good tutorial sites to get you started.

Comment: Lookup each of your questions individually and start from there. Google "how to execute a vlookup in VBA" or "how to find last row using vba". Once you have something that you are working with, showing what you are trying to do, you'll probably get more help.